# How to fix failed to import DAGs due to 30s timeout errors?

Tags: airflow, mwaa

We have multiple mw1.large MWAA environments and we are seeing import errors everyday which say
`airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: DagBag import timeout for ..dag_name.py after 30.0s`.

They are not blocking anything as they disappear quickly. The errors point to best practices doc but I don't think our DAGs are particularly complex. We see at least 1 import error every day in all environments.

Want to know if there are any other recommendations apart from increasing the timeout.

Comment: Do you  have any use of Variables at top level Python code of DAGs?

Answer (score 3):

You can try increasing the [dagbag import timeout](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dagbag-import-timeout). Also, review your DAGs for [top-level code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code), which is considered an Airflow antipattern.